# Подключение к БД с помощью hubernate

Tags: hibernate, java-ee, maven, glassfish

При подключении библиотеки hibernate к веб проекту столкнулся с проблемой создания фабрики сессий. В чем проблема не могу понять. В обычном java приложении все прекрасно работает. В веб брыкается.

Вот так создаю фабрику.

```
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(Class clazz) {
        return new Configuration()
            .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
            .addAnnotatedClass(clazz)
            .buildSessionFactory();
    }
```

Вот xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate_test?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">123321</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">30</property>

    <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Set the current session context -->
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <mapping class="com.chessman.work.entity.ProfField" />
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Зависисмости в pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>testg</groupId>
    <artifactId>art</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>ChessmanWork</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <version.java>1.8</version.java>
        <version.java-web>7.0</version.java-web>
        <version.hibernate>5.3.7.Final</version.hibernate>
        <version.mysql-connector>8.0.13</version.mysql-connector>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Logback to print the logs generated by Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Core of Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${version.hibernate}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${version.hibernate}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${version.mysql-connector}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>${version.java-web}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${version.java}</source>
                    <target>${version.java}</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Вот лог:

```
Info:   Loading application [ChessmanWork] at [/ChessmanWork]
Info:   ChessmanWork was successfully deployed in 9 686 milliseconds.
Info:   Initializing Mojarra 2.3.2 ( 20170627-2139 e63598abf2ed2bb1a24674f308a734e0dce18a72) for context ''
Info:   Loading application [__admingui] at [/]
Info:   Loading application __admingui done in 9 824 ms
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.7.Final}
Info:   HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
WARN:   HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
Info:   HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
WARN:   HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Info:   HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate_test?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&serverTimezone=UTC]
Severe:   Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
Info:   HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Info:   HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Info:   HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 30 (min=1)
WARN:   HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : null
Info:   HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Info:   HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
WARN:   SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08000
ERROR:   Cannot open file:D:\Developer\Servers\glassfish-5.0\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[Accaunt]: Servlet.service() for servlet Accaunt threw exception
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at com.chessman.work.classes.hibernate.HListProfFields.<init>(HListProfFields.java:36)
    at com.chessman.work.servlets.Accaunt.processRequest(Accaunt.java:33)
    at com.chessman.work.servlets.Accaunt.doGet(Accaunt.java:54)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:686)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.addConnections(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder.build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot open file:D:\Developer\Servers\glassfish-5.0\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:70)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.SSLParamsException: Cannot open file:D:\Developer\Servers\glassfish-5.0\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.getSSLContext(ExportControlled.java:493)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:301)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:188)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:99)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:347)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:777)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:486)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:202)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1442)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:165)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:955)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:780)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.getSSLContext(ExportControlled.java:473)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:778)
    ... 81 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась достаточно просто:
нужно отключить SSL в запросе

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">
   jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate_test?
   useSSL=FALSE&amp;
   zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&amp;
   serverTimezone=UTC
</property>
```

P.S. не забываем, что указывая знак `&` в xml при запросе для разделения параметров будет выдавать ошибку. Поэтому необходимо вместо него использовать `&amp;`.